# FindFiles on a drive letter fails but passes on path

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi

I am using the following code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <commdlg.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

// This function is an abomination -- I just wrote it to be quick.
std::wstring CombinePaths(std::wstring const &pattern, LPCWSTR filename) {
    std::wstring tmp(pattern);
    tmp.push_back('\0');
    PathRemoveFileSpec(&tmp[0]);
    std::wstring retVal(MAX_PATH, '\0');
    PathCombine(&retVal[0], tmp.c_str(), filename);
    return retVal.c_str();
}

void FindFiles(std::wstring const &pattern) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(pattern.c_str(), &fd);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        wprintf(L"FindFirstFile.  Err=%d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    do {
        std::wstring fullPath = CombinePaths(pattern, fd.cFileName);
        wprintf(L"FullPath=%s\n", fullPath.c_str());
    } while (FindNextFile(h, &fd));

    FindClose(h);
}

int main()
{
    FindFiles(L"c:\\Windows"); //Passes
    FindFiles(L"c:\\"); //Fails
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it not pass on `C:\\` ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: *Why does it not pass ...* -- Please post the relevant error messages, error return codes, etc.

Comment: I am not sure how to get an error message. I am looking that up now

Comment: Don't you mean to pass `"C:\\*"` ?

Comment: @MistyD See `FormatMessage`.

Comment: @BenVoigt that would return all the folders

Comment: It would return the items inside the directory.  That's the whole point of using directory enumeration such as `FindFirstFile` (Windows) or `opendir` (*nix).

Comment: The error code I am getting is 2 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Are you trying to get a `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure filled in for the root directory itself?  Please tell us what your code is intended to do.

Comment: I am trying to determine if its a valid path or the drive exists. Normally i would do this with a usb drive

Comment: @MistyD -- [See this for error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Also why are you not printing out some intermediate values, so you have an idea what you're exactly using in the API calls?

Comment: Pass it to `CreateFile` with no access to see if it is a valid path.  Or `GetFileAttributes`.  No need to call `FindFirstFile` to see if something exists.

Comment: You might also need `Set(Thread)ErrorMode` to avoid a popup when trying to query a drive that doesn't exist.

Comment: Have a look at [`PathFileExists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584.aspx): "*Determines whether a path to a file system object such as a file **or folder** is valid.*" Or [`PathIsDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773621.aspx): "*Verifies that a path is a **valid directory**.*"

Answer (score 1):

From the [`FindFirstFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx) documentation:

> ```
> HANDLE WINAPI FindFirstFile(
>   _In_  LPCTSTR           lpFileName,
>   _Out_ LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> lpFileName [in]
>
> The directory or path, and the file name. The file name can include wildcard characters, for example, an asterisk (*) or a question mark (?).
>
> This parameter should not be NULL, an invalid string (for example, an empty string or a string that is missing the terminating null character), or **end in a trailing backslash ().**

(Emphasis mine)

This means you simply can't pass `C:\` as the parameter and expect it to work.

That said, you should not be using `FindFirstFile()` to check if a directory exists. That's a bit like taking a 12 gauge shotgun to kill a mosquito: it works, but it is overkill.

[`GetFileAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944.aspx) is the function you should be using.

Comment: Overkill works, except when it doesn't.  FindFirstFile reads the directory entry in the parent directory.  A drive root doesn't *have* a parent directory.  Might work to pass `"C:\\."` (which also obeys the rule of not ending in backslash)

Comment: Also for drive root directories in particular, [`GetVolumeInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx) is a good choice.  Or [`GetDriveType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @BenVoigt, the root directory listing in NTFS and FAT file systems doesn't contain a "." entry for itself. Also, matching the "." entry in a subdirectory requires wildcards -- at least `"` (i.e. [`DOS_DOT`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2017/06/04/wildcards-in-windows)) -- to get around the requirement for a valid filename, e.g. `L"C:\\Temp\\\""`.